# Can I set a timer to auto record with an 744T?

Tags: sound, sound-devices, record

I recentley got an sd 744t. I love it and was wondering if i can pre-setup a recording for later that night.
For example I leave the recorder in a certain place and want it to record for 3 days at 00:00h at night for 5 minutes on each day?
as far as I understood it would only be possible with a camera linked through timecode that gives the signal to record. Is there any device I could attach to the timecode slot that sets a recording time? or am I missing an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 744T [user guide](http://cdn.sounddevices.com/download/guides/744t_en.pdf) mentions :

> The 744T is equipped with a record start and stop timer. This allows a
> user to record a take at a specific time from an unattended recorder.
> Set the start time in the Setup Menu option  REC: TIMER START  then
> set the record stop time in the Setup Menu option   REC: TIMER STOP.
> The 744T will only start recording if the recorder is On when the
> timer start time elapses.

So you should check wether this operates as you wish when using the internal date/time clock (which is separate from the TC generator). It would imply having a power supply that allow to keep the recorder on for several days, and check wether it works several consecutive days at the same time.

**EDIT**

The OP mentions that it is working as expected on a one time record.

Comment: sorry, was looking for it, but must have missed it! and  thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, i will check with the guys at sd If there is any external device to realise multiple recordings. - Thx though!